# MSSQL Update statement - String or binary data would be truncated. [Pyodbc]

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc

I'm using Python ODBC to execute an update statement on my MSSQL server and am receiving the following error:

```
pyodbc.DataError: ('22001', '[22001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated. (8152) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

The SQL statement runs fine when ran in a terminal, but my Python version does not work.

Works: `update tblAddress set txtEmail2 = '256245624565@645.com' where tblAddressID  = 5345`

Not Working:

```
updateKey = txtEmail2
updateValue = "256245624565@645.com"
tblAddressID = 91031
cursor.execute("""update tblAddress set ? =  ? where tblAddressID = ? """, 
updateKey, updateValue , tblAddressID)
```

Confused by the truncation error. I have tried .encode('utf8') my updateValue incase the @ symbol was being weird but this didn't work.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You cannot use parameterization for field names. `set ? =` is not valid. Also, I think you need to enclose the parameters in parentheses to be considered a single tuple/list argument to `execute`

Comment: thanks rogan.  I've changed the format to `cursor.execute("""update tblAddress set """+updateKey+""" =  ? where tblAddressID = ? """, 
updateKey, updateValue , tblAddressID)` and that works. Is this now vulnerable to sql injection though? The program uses input values for field names.

Comment: I'm trying to find the best dupe. Yes, you are correct, unfortunately you are responsible for sanitizing that input yourself, it cannot be escaped.

Comment: If it uses user input, I guess you need to check their field names against a list of the database schema before executing the query